# Why Form needs to be set to null?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, null, dispose

I'm learning C #, the example programs that I have seen I find code like this:

```
static CalibrationForm form = null;
```

and this

```
public static void HideCalibration()
{
 form.Hide();
 form.Dispose();
 form = null;
}
```

Is there any particular reason why the form should be set to null?

What is the meaning of a form is set to null?

Comment: Yeuch; static fields... whatever samples you are reading: they're horrid

Comment: `Is there any particular reason...` - yes, that's because the examples you're looking at are **extremely wrong** and should be erradicated from the face of Earth right now. For one, winforms is an obsolete technology and it is really prone to the introduction of code smells everywhere. I suggest you start learning the basics of C# by doing some Console Applications and then move to WPF and MVVM when you are ready to create Windows GUIs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this (IMO poor) example, `form` is a `static` field that holds a reference to the form instance that is going to be available from all locations in the application. The problem is that `Dispose()` ***is not enough*** - it cannot be garbage collected if it is referenced by a `static` field, because `static` fields **do not go out of scope**. Ever. Setting the field to `null` allows the instance to be collected.

Note also that **any** references to the form will keep it alive - not just this field; *event* subscriptions are notorious ways to keep things alive artificially.

But emphasis: that is a horrid example. I do not recommend coding with forms in `static` fields.

Comment: so how can I get the same results with the above code, but in the right way? 

in the case when the form is displayed, all the resources in this form is reseted. 

I found this code in a program created in 2009.

Comment: @user3332360 without knowing what uses the `form` field, that is impossible to answer; but as a general rule, you would **make the instance available** to everything that needed it - for example via a property: `someRandomForm.CalibrationForm = someExistingCalibrationInstance`.

Comment: For example, this form is used to create an image for the purpose of calibrating the screen size. So how can I do that? So i get the same result as code obove.
In the original code written by @ johnny chung lee I also found the method form.Dispose when the ESC key is pressed. but I did not find any form is converted into a static field or the form is set to null.

Comment: If an application is supposed to have a form which behaves as a singleton shared among all document windows, I would think a reference to it would have to live in either a static field somewhere or else a field in a singleton somewhere; in either case, setting the field to null would be proper if the form is killed, but to free up the memory it would use and also let any "show form" code know that the form will need to be re-created.  What pattern would be better?

Answer (score 0):

It is to make sure all references in memory to `form` are gone. There is no other reason, and in fact I believe it has no further use whatsoever.

In fact, what the CLR does is keeping a managed heap containing all class, class doesn't have any references any more, it can be garbage collected, otherwise it doesn't.

In this case, the `Dispose` removed the Win32 handles, but not the memory allocated from the .NET part, so that's why you set it to null.

Read [this on GC internals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx).

Comment: This reference count system is used in COM/COM+ but not in .NET. The CLR uses some kind of rechable tree to identify the objects in scope

Answer (score 0):

The final line in the `HideCalibration` method is probably to remove the reference to the form, so that the garbage collector can remove it and free up a bit of memory on the heap.

The first line (`static CalibrationForm form = null;`) is simply to make it obvious what the initial value of the static variable is.